# Reset Windows 7 sync

Tags: windows-7, sync

My company uses sync centre on our Windows 7 PCs to keep network files available off line. However I have a number of files which have been deleted on my local machine and are causing sync conflict errors. The side effect of this is that every time sync centre tries to run a sync my computer slows to a crawl. Sync centres methods for resolving conflicts have not been able to fix the issue.

Is there a way to reset/re-build the sync database so that the errors are eliminated and fresh/new copy of the database is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this post: http://offlinefiles.blogspot.ca/2010/09/delete-offline-files-cache-windows-7.html to clear the cache, however it has had side effect of eliminating all sync partnerships.

After re-establishing the sync partnerships, first sync took a long time due to the size of the network folder being synchronized, but was ultimately successful.